# how to update using nested query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that runs on a table, and pulls out 2 fields.
I want to take them, and using UPDATE sentence, to use their values as WHERE and SET.

For example:

```
select name, address from xxx.....
```

I want to take the name & address and do this

```
update yyy 
set fullname=(name I pulled before) 
where address=(address I pulled before)
```

thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is... Can you give a more specific example, with some code?

Comment: Both table structure needed what is the name of field which make relation with both tables

Comment: please explain your need provide your table structure or something like that explain the thing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give this a try

```
Update t
Set t.yyyy = q.Name
From TableToUpdate t
Join AddressTable q on q.Address = t.Address
```

This assumes that Address field (which you are joining on) is a one to one relationship with the Address field in the table you are updating

This can also be written

```
Update TableToUpdate
Set yyyy = q.Name
From AddressTable q
WHERE q.Address = TableToUpdate.Address
```

Since the update table is accessible in the FROM/WHERE clauses, except it cannot be aliased.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or up (which you didn't specify ....), you can use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
;WITH UpdateData AS
(
    SELECT
          FullName,
          Address
    FROM 
          dbo.SomeTableYouUse
    WHERE
          (some critiera)
)
UPDATE dbo.yyy 
SET fullname = ud.FullName
FROM UpdateData ud
WHERE address = ud.Address
```

Inside your CTE, you can figure out how to determine your `FullName` and `Address`, and the CTE is sort of an "inline" view which is valid for the next statement only - in this case, for the `UPDATE` statement.